# Reject new cell input based on the actual cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using Conditional formmating or Data validation rules, How can i reject a new input in a cell if it's less than the old value of the cell.

thank you.

i have tried conditional formatting using this formula `=columnX<$column$X`  but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need a helper column that is the value of the cell (for calculation order of operations) but ultimately this is just a standard Data Validation rule where the value is greater than or equal to.

If cell A2 is your value with a validation rule then apply the validation as seen in the image below (Greater than or equal to `=VALUE(helper cell)`)

In the helper column of your choosing use `=A2`

[image: Example]

When I enter a number less than 10...

[image: Example2]